# Различие в способе приведения к целому числу

Tags: c#

Чем отличается `int.parse` от `convert.toInt32` ?

Answer (score 7):

Разница в том, что если вы передадите null в int.Parse то получите исключение. А в случае с Convert.ToInt32 получите 0. Convert.ToInt32 сначала проверяет свой аргумент на null, и если условие верно, то возвращает 0, в противном случае вызывает Int32.Parse

Кроме того, если посмотрите на перезрузки, то можете увидеть, что Int32.Parse также может принимать  дополнительные аргументы, в которых могут задаваться, например, региональные параметры представления числовых данных

Comment: Тогда в чем разница между int.TryParse и Convert.ToInt?

Comment: Вы прикалываетесь, или всерьез спрашиваете?